# Issue getting Airbnb calendar using PHP cUrl

Tags: php, json, curl, calendar, icalendar

I am trying to get the airbnb calendar for my clients listings using the [unofficial Airbnb API](http://airbnbapi.org/#get-calendar-info).

The API uses a cUrl to retrieve the calendar:

```
curl -X POST --compressed 
-H "X-Airbnb-OAuth-Token: 9nwld6we4td9vkwj160teb49a" 
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" 
--data-binary '{"operations":[{"method":"GET","path":"/calendar_days","query":{"start_date":"2016-01-30","listing_id":"12132179","_format":"host_calendar","end_date":"2017-03-30"}},{"method":"GET","path":"/dynamic_pricing_controls/12132179","query":{}}],"_transaction":false}' 
https://api.airbnb.com/v2/batch/?client_id=3092nxybyb0otqw18e8nh5nty&locale=en-US&currency=USD
```

I have tested it using [Hurl.it](https://www.hurl.it/?url=https%3A//api.airbnb.com/v2/batch/%3Fclient_id%3D3092nxybyb0otqw18e8nh5nty%26locale%3Den-US%26currency%3DUSD&method=POST&headers=%7B%22Content-Type%22%3A%5B%22application/json%3B%20charset%3DUTF-8%22%5D%2C%22X-Airbnb-OAuth-Token%22%3A%5B%229nwld6we4td9vkwj160teb49a%22%5D%7D&body=%7B%22operations%22%3A%5B%7B%22method%22%3A%22GET%22%2C%22path%22%3A%22/calendar_days%22%2C%22query%22%3A%7B%22start_date%22%3A%222016-01-30%22%2C%22listing_id%22%3A%2212132179%22%2C%22_format%22%3A%22host_calendar%22%2C%22end_date%22%3A%222017-03-30%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22method%22%3A%22GET%22%2C%22path%22%3A%22/dynamic_pricing_controls/12132179%22%2C%22query%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%2C%22_transaction%22%3Afalse%7D) so I know it works. The problem is I don't know the correct way to send the `--data-binary` section using PHP. My current PHP code is:

```
$query = '{"operations":{"method":"GET","path":"/calendar_days","query":{"start_date":"' . date('Y-m-d') . '","listing_id":"' . $propertyID . '","_format":"host_calendar","end_date":"' . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 year')) . '"}},"_transaction":false}';

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.airbnb.com/v2/batch/?client_id=$client_id",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "Content-Type" => "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        "X-Airbnb-OAuth-Token" => $token
    ],
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $query
));

$calendar = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");`

and set CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER to TRUE

(and maybe also set X-Airbnb-API-Key: client_id_here )